# Why is this div height returning 0?

Tags: javascript, css, height

I am completely stuck on this one. I'm trying to get the height of a div, but it's constantly returning 0, despite trying numerous ways to resolve the problem. Here's the code.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const topDrawer = document.querySelector('.drawer__container--top');
  console.log(topDrawer.offsetHeight)
})
```

```css
    .drawer {
    
        &__container {
            width: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            width: 90%;
            background: white;
            height: 500px;
            // left: 50%;
            transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
            border-radius: 1rem;
            box-shadow: 0px 3px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            z-index: 3;
            &--top {
                top: 0;
                // transform: translateY(-400px) translateX(-50%);
                
            }
    
            &--bottom {
                bottom: 0;
                transform: translateY(60vh) translateX(-50%);
                padding: 1rem 2rem;
                &.open {
                    transform: translateY(8vh) translateX(-50%);
                }
            }
        }
```

```html
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@latest/dist/ionic/ionic.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule="" src="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@latest/dist/ionic/ionic.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@latest/css/ionic.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Actor&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- This is the main body - every thing will go in here! -->
<div class="main">
    <div class="jp__header">
        <div class="jp__header__textrel">
            <div class="jp__header__textabs">
                <h1>Journey Planner</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="jp__header__weatherabs">
                <canvas id="icon2"></canvas>
            </div>
            <div class="jp__header__underline"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="drawer drawer__container drawer__container--top">
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div class="drawer__container drawer__container--bottom">
        <div class="drawer__search__wrapper">
            <ion-toolbar class="drawer__search__toolbar" no-shadow="">
                <ion-searchbar animated="" class="drawer__search__searchbar" mode="ios"
                    placeholder="Enter a bus stop number..."></ion-searchbar>
            </ion-toolbar>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried
- wrapping this in windo.addEventListener("load", () etc)
as well as using this 'ready' function:

```
function ready(callback){
    // in case the document is already rendered
    if (document.readyState!='loading') callback();
    // modern browsers
    else if (document.addEventListener) document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', callback);
    // IE <= 8
    else document.attachEvent('onreadystatechange', function(){
        if (document.readyState=='complete') callback();
    });
}
```

- using document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded")

Also there are no floats anywhere but I have tried adding overflow: hidden.

I'm packaging with webpack, but the bundle is being put just before the closing body tag. I see no reason why a height of 500px isn't being returned...hope you can help.

EDIT: I'm using Django and templates too - could that be affecting it?

SECOND EDIT:
There seems to be a tiny delay in the styles being applied, as detected by @Thomas below. Applying a set timeout seems to get things working so I'm going to go with that... pretty baffling.

Comment: Would you please put the **rendered** HTML into the question, not the framework code that renders HTML.  You're asking people to go to a considerable amount of work inventing a whole bunch of stuff in order to replicate your problem.  You should provide a [mcve], but supplying the rendered HTML may be enough.

Comment: Sorry, that was stupid, editing now

Comment: Might want to pay attention to that warning from `ionic`

Comment: Ah interesting! I didn't think of that, I'll sort that now

Comment: Sadly no change

Comment: There's absolutely nothing in `'.drawer__container--top'`, of course it's height is 0

Comment: Can't divs have standalone heights?

Comment: I've set its height to 500px?

Comment: Also every other element on the page is rendering with a height of 0, I've just checked it

Comment: The style *was* set to 500 px, but whatever is applying `element.style` is overriding it.  Know zero about `ionic`, but a quick google suggests that might be the culprit.

Comment: for some reason, the styles have not been applied (yet). I've made a *(last resort)* test, polling the value. It changes after 7-8 frames to 500px.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, why do you think that would be?

Comment: I don't know and tbh. It's too hot here in my area to think/debug that kind of stuff right now. sry and good luck. Maybe I'll take a nother look in a few hours when it cooled down.

Comment: Haha no problem, thanks and stay safe!!

Comment: @Raph117 about the delay... the CSS used in the example is not standard CSS, there is a good chance that ionic is parsing and converting the text from styles tags when it loads... that can explain the delay. Try the sample example with normal css rules like: `.drawer__container--top { height: 500px; }` instead of using the nested syntax

Answer (score 0):

Foudn the answer to this: Many thanks to @Tibrogargan, @Thomas and @Diego for helping identify it.

The issue was the ionic import:

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@latest/css/ionic.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

The scripts are not loading in until that css file has been sourced. I've solved it by adding a setTimeout of 2ms to the document load handler, but am also going to look into how to either source the css locally or find another solution.